# Get an specific value in <a> html with javascript-ajax Django

Tags: javascript, python, html, ajax, django

I'm using Django and Python 3.

I have this in my HTML code:

```
{% for category in categories() %}
    <li class="c-menu__item fs-xsmall">
        <a href="#" id="next-category">
            {{ category}}
        </a>
    </li>
    <input type="hidden" value="{{ category.code }}" id="category-id">
{% endfor %}
<div class="col-xs-4" id="sub_categories">
</div>
```

That lists few categories.

And I have this in my script:

```
$( document ).on( 'click', '#next-category', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        url : 'product_category/addAjax',
        type : 'POST',
        data : {
            category: $( '#category-id').val(),
        },
    })
    .fail(function( jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown ){
        console.log('FAIL');
    })
    .done(function(data){
        console.log('DONE');
        $('#sub_categories').prop('innerHTML',data["sub_categories"]);

    });
    return false;
});
```

When I print: $( '#category-id').val(), I always get the same value. It doesn't matter if I choose the first category listed or the last one, I will always get the same value. I have no idea what's wrong.

Comment: How are you choosing the second one?

Comment: You print many `<input ... id="category-id">` but all of the has the same id

Comment: Little confused what you are trying to accomplish.. but if you are trying to associate the category.code with the link.. so that when the link is clicked you get the code for that category, you need to put your hidden input within the link tag so you can find the correct one.  Or, just use a data attribute, eg:  `<li class="c-menu__item fs-xsmall" data-code="{{ category.code }}">` and forget the input tag.

Comment: Then you can do `$( document ).on( 'click', '#next-category', function(e){
    e.preventDefault(); alert($(this).attr("data-code")); });`

Comment: Also `{% for category in categories() %}` not sure how that is not causing an exception, when you should not have the parenthesis in there.

Answer (score 0):

**Gocht comment is the correct answer.**
Since you want to iterate over  tags they should have different id's !!!

The simple work around is to use a class and evaluate correct id:

```
{% for category in categories() %}
    <li class="c-menu__item fs-xsmall">
        <a href="#" class="next-category" value="{{ forloop.counter }}" >
            {{ category}}
        </a>
    </li>
    <input type="hidden" value="{{ category.code }}" id="category-id-{{ forloop.counter }}">
{% endfor %}
<div class="col-xs-4" id="sub_categories">
</div>
```

script :

```
$( document ).on( 'click', '.next-category', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var id = $(this).attr("value");
    var input_id = "#category-id-" + id;

    $.ajax({
        url : 'product_category/addAjax',
        type : 'POST',
        data : {
            category: $(input_id).val(),
        },
    })
    .fail(function( jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown ){
        console.log('FAIL');
    })
    .done(function(data){
        console.log('DONE');
        $('#sub_categories').prop('innerHTML',data["sub_categories"]);

    });
    return false;
});
```

Comment: Thanks! I tried changing "value" for "name" in the HTML and fixing the .js it worked

Comment: Great Marisela, think of marking the answer as correct, it helps !  ;-)